# Video full-screen can't detect on ended

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, dom

I have a **video** component that triggers some functionality when the video ends.

By default (not full-screen state), the onEnded triggers correctly. However, in the full-screen state my function doesn't trigger.

How can I detect **onEnded** while in full-screen video?

```js
 <video
              id={...}
              poster={...}
              onPlaying={...}
              onEnded={() => {
                // some functions while doesn't trigger in full-screen 
                setIsPlaying(false);
                setIsEnded(true);
              }}
              controls={...}
            >
              <source src={src} />
</video>
```

Comment: Please include a code sample that demonstrates the bug. Also your code sample doesn't seem to make much sense with a separate `<source>` tag.